# Using MySQL ver. 5.5.55 in a production env

Tags: mysql-5.5

Is it still OK to use this older version of MySQL on a production web server (LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04)? It's a low traffic volume business website. Loads fast enough. So far, no serious issues (like being hacked or something).
Also we use older version of PhpMyAdmin (ver. 4.0), so my question also regarding this too.

Answer (score 0):

There are four reasons to upgrade the software:

- Significant bug was removed
- Security breach was removed
- Hardware have
  to be changed
- Database structure was modified dramatically and
  require some features not available in the older versions.

Updates performed just for software actuality are inappropriate in the production.

`phpMyAdmin` is well-known as unsecure software with lot of breaches so its location should be at least password-protected and restricted to the secure subnet(s).

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL 5.5 hasn't reached its EOL (like what happened to PHP 5.5 recently). That's why I keep using MySQL 5.5 I'm not aware of any serious issues with it and neither our hardware nor db structure require any changes. So I guess there's no need to upgrade MySQL for now...

Comment: Even when EOL will be reached if it fits your needs and secure. Unfortunately, phpMyAdmin increases the risks alot.

Comment: We have Web Application Firewall enabled and also the URL for phpMyAdmin is different (not mysite.com/phpmyadmin). Also there's fail2ban server and, of course, HTTPS.